# Direct comparison with sin(n): $\frac{\sin n}{n^2}< \frac1{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

I would like to know why $\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2} < \frac{1}{n^2}$? It becomes obvious when you look at a graph, but for instances where you can’t do that how do you tell if the comparison is true?

Comment: $sin(x)$ is bounded in fact it is always less than or equal to 1.

Comment: I guess you mean when $n$ is an integer?

Comment: Well, I mean in all the real line

Comment: @DanielOrdoñez $\sin (\pi / 2) = 1$

Comment: $$ \forall x\geq 0,\qquad \sin(x)\leq \min(1,x).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\quad{n \in \mathbb{N} \to \\ n \text{ can't be } \frac{k\pi}{2} 
\\n \in \mathbb{N} \neq \frac{k\pi}{2} \in \mathbb{Q^c}\\\to 
-1\leq \sin(n) \leq 1 \bf{\text{ turn into } }\\ -1< \sin(n) <1 \\so\\\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2}< \frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have that $\sin(x) = 1$ if and only if $x$ is $\pi/2 +2k\pi$ for some integer $k$.

$$\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q},$$

hence $\sin(n) \neq 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. As $|\sin(x)|\le 1$ you find out that $\sin(n)<1$, therefore your strict inequality.